# What data structure should I use for integer pairs?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, data-structures, key-value

I am trying to optimize my code to speed up calculations and reduce memory consumption. I need to store data for the year and the cost. Currently I use fixed arrays to hold values.

For example, I would have an integer array:

```
integer[0] = 0,  
integer[1] = 200,  
integer[2] = 0,  
integer[3] = 0,  
integer[4] = 200,  
integer[5] = 0,  
...   
integer[99] = 0
```

Where integer[0] = 0 means at year 2015 is cost is $0, integer[1] = 200 means at 2016 the cost is $200 and so on. Since I have millions of these arrays held in memory and used for calculations, I want to minimize the memory and performance impact.

To clarify, the way I use the data is for charting purposes. Once I assign costs to the years, I sum up the arrays based on the object series they are part of. Then I display them in a stacked bar chart.

Is there a better way of storing my data? I'm considering key-value list so I only store the non-zero costs and year but I don't know if that would help much.

Comment: The best answer will depend heavily on how, exactly, you are using this data.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Diosjenin I added some information. Hope that helps?

Comment: It does. The only issue I see with Jacob's answer is that the Dictionary won't internally keep elements sorted by year, so you'll have to either a) iterate over the dictionary and sort them yourself (using LINQ or a custom function), or b) iterate over known years and see whether the dictionary contains each year as a key.  If either of those would be an acceptable performance tradeoff, then a Dictionary will suit you fine.  If not, let us know.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `Dictionary<int, int>`:

```
var costs = new Dictionary<int, int> {
    { 2014, 150 },
    { 2016, 200 },
};
```

It may not use up less memory necessarily, but you can avoid storing empty entries, and the meaning of the data is a bit more obvious.

Comment: This is an example of the "_I'm considering key-value list_".  It's also a good answer.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Do you think this would result in a significant increase in performance compared to how I currently do it?

Comment: It will not. Depending on the size of your data, it may save memory consumption, but an array is going to be much faster.

Comment: @AC The real improvement is in readability.  Something like `costByYear[2016]` makes more sense than `costByYear[1]`.

Comment: @Jacob "an array is going to be much faster" Why do you think this?  Dictionary lookup is O(1) which is the same as an array.  The only difference is a call to `GetHashCode` to find the right bucket and calls to `Equals` on all keys within that bucket.

Comment: @Jacob, I see. My main goal was in increase performance & reduce memory. Otherwise it may not be worth the effort to alter my whole project just for readability.

Comment: Also worth noting that if these arrays are very large, or if there are very many of them, the performance improvement brought from a small dictionary fitting into cache might outweigh the drop from taking time to hash keys.

Comment: @DStanley, O(1) doesn't always mean faster, it just means it will scale well. That constant time is non-zero. O(1) with a dictionary is slower than the O(1) with an array. That was my main point.

Comment: @Jacob I understand that - and agree that arrays are faster that dictionaries, but "much faster" seems like an exaggeration.  I'd hate for the OP to decide not to use dictionaries based on the false assumption that they are "much slower".

Comment: This would use a huge amount more memory than an array, and would be considerably slower in performance. Whereas the dictionary approach does have the advantage of readability (i.e. `costByYear[2016]`), you can make the array indexing quite readable with `costByYear[2016-baseYear]`.

Comment: Yeah, if performance is the only consideration here, you can't get better than the array.

Comment: @A C - Since your numbers are small you might consider using `short` instead of `int` to reduce your memory consumption. If you want to reduce it further then you can compress the numbers, but then performance might go down as well.

Answer (score 1):

If (1) all you are doing is summing, and (2) don't require lookup access to any given value but are simply iterating through them, and (3) your values are truly sparse,

then something like

```
integer[0] = 200,  
integer[1] = 200,  
...
```

combined with

```
year[0] = 2016,
year[1] = 2019,
...
```

will get you a minimum memory footprint, without loss of efficiency.  Dictionaries (hashes) cost memory; an array is most economical for memory footprint, and even more so if you have a default value (0) that can be assumed for omitted years.  But this only works if you don't need to do lookup, since with this structure that's an O(n) exercise.